# *TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined* when implementing REST API with nodejs to add new data to database

Tags: node.js, json, rest, api

I have to implement (with node.js) a REST API to add a new client to database (using the POST method). I have to use Postman to test that API.

I am having following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined**

Here is my code:

*customerController.js*

```
const sql = require('../db/customerSQL');
module.exports = {

   createCustomers: async (req, res) => {
       console.log("createCustomer: ", req.body);
       try {
           let nimi = req.query.nimi;
           let osoite = req.query.osoite;
           let postinro = req.query.postinro;
           let postitmp = req.query.postitmp;
           let luontipvm = req.query.luontipvm;
           let asty_avain = req.query.asty_avain;

           let c = await sql.createCustomers(nimi, osoite, postinro, postitmp, luontipvm, 
           asty_avain);
           console.log("Next");
           res.statusCode = 201;
           res.json({ status: "OK" });
       }
      catch (err) {
        console.log("Not working! ", err)
        res.status = 400;
        res.json({ status: "NOT OK", msg: err });
      }
  }
}
```

*customerSQL.js*

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'restUser',      
   password: 'restUser123!',
   database: 'Customer',
   dateStrings : true
});

module.exports = {


createCustomers: (req, res) => {

    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        let query = "INSERT INTO asiakas (NIMI, OSOITE, POSTINRO, POSTITMP, LUONTIPVM, ASTY_AVAIN) 
         VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        console.log("query:" + query);
        console.log(req.body);

         connection.query(query, [req.body.NIMI, req.body.OSOITE, req.body.POSTINRO, 
         req.body.POSTITMP,req.body.ASTY_AVAIN], function (error, result, fields) {

            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            else {
                resolve(result);
            }
         });
     })
  }
}
```

*customerRoutes.js*

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

let ctrl = require('../controllers/customerController');


// Postman: localhost:3000/asiakas
router.route('/asiakas')
post(ctrl.createCustomers); 

module.exports = router;
```

*index.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 3000;
var hostname = "127.0.0.1";

var cors = function (req, res, next)

{
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
next();
}

app.use(cors);

const customerRoutes = require('./routes/customerRoutes');
app.use(customerRoutes);

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Just tried your code and it works, except I had to change `post(ctrl.createCustomers)` to `.post(ctrl.createCustomers)` in customerRoutes.js

Answer (score -1):

```
 const sql = require('../db/customerSQL');

 module.exports = {


createCustomers : (req, res) => {
    console.log("createCustomer: ", req.body);

    res.statusCode = 201;
    if ( req.body.NIMI == null ){
        res.status = 400;
        res.json({status : "NOT OK", msg : "Name is missing"})
        return;

    else{
      sql.createCustomers(req,res);
    }
},
```

}